# Extract particular point of URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, extract

I'm trying to get a very specific part of a URL using PHP so that I can use it as a variable later on.

The URL I have is:

> https://forums.mydomain.com/index.php?/clubs/11-Default-Club

The particular part I am trying to extract is the `11` part between the `/clubs/` and `-Default-Club` bits.

I was wondering what the best way to do this was. I've seen examples on here that use a regex-esque parser but I can't wrap my head around it for this particular instance.

Thanks

Edit; this is what I've tried so far using an explode query, but it seems to give me all sorts of elements which are not present in the URL above:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = explode('/', $url);
$url = array_filter($url);
$url = array_merge($url, array());
```

Which returns:

```
Array ( [0] => index.php?app=core&module=system&controller=widgets&do=getBlock&blockID=plugin_9_bimBlankWidget_dqtr03ssz&pageApp=core&pageModule=clubs&pageController=view&pageArea=header&orientation=horizontal&csrfKey=8e19769b95c733b05439755827a98ac8 )
```

Comment: Show your current attempt

Comment: Regex seems like overkill. A simple [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) should work in this case. You should start by making some attempts. If you can't get it working, come back, show us what you've tried, expected result, the result you're getting and we can help you from there.

Comment: @AleksG added as requested.

Comment: The code you added makes no sense.  Looks more like a random collection of method calls. Also, I can't see at all how you can possibly get the result you showed from the input URL. What you want is to use `explode` to split by `/` character, then use `explode` again to split by `-` character.

Comment: If that is the only number in the url you can use [filter_var()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to only get the INT part

Comment: @AleksG thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a go at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect that the string with dashes (`11-Default-Club`) will be always at the end you can try this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlParts = explode('/', $url);
$string = end($urlParts);
$stringParts = explode('-', $string);
$theNumber = $stringParts[0]; // this will be 11
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather be explicit:

```
<?php
$url     = 'https://forums.mydomain.com/index.php?/clubs/11-Default-Club';
$query   = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$pattern = '@^/clubs/(\d+)[a-zA-Z-]+$@';
$digits  = preg_match($pattern, $query, $matches)
            ? $matches[1]
            : null;

var_dump($digits);
```

Output:

```
string(2) "11"
```

Comment: This is the only valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

If this url structure is fix for all URLs in your site then below is best way to get your value.

```
<?php
$url = "https://forums.mydomain.com/index.php?/clubs/11-Default-Club";
$url = explode('/', $url);
$url = array_filter($url);
$end = end($url);
$end_parts = explode('-',$end);
echo $end_parts[0];
```

Output:

```
11
```

Comment: Why is this the best way?

Comment: because using this you can get expected result properly. do you have any other way then you can give answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this URL structure is fix for all URLs in your site and you only want to get the integer/number/digit part of the URL:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://forums.mydomain.com/index.php?/clubs/11-Default-Club';
$int = (int) filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo $int;
```

Comment: What if there is a number before the `clubs` url part?

Comment: As of now a number before the `clubs` part is not part of the question. (That's why I mentioned "_If this URL structure is fix for all URLs_")